# Issues with Microphone Permissions Not Prompting After Code Signing with Hardened Runtime

Tags: macos, pyinstaller

I'm developing a macOS app with Python and PyInstaller, and I've hit a roadblock with microphone permissions. The app prompts for microphone access correctly when running unsigned. However, after signing with the hardened runtime option, the prompt no longer appears, and the app can't access the mic.

Here's what my setup looks like:

- Python app packaged with PyInstaller
- Entitlements file with `com.apple.security.device.microphone` and `com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory`
- Signing command:

  ```
  codesign --deep --force --verify --timestamp --verbose --sign "Developer ID Application: [******]" --options=runtime --entitlements ./entitlements.plist main.app
  ```
- entitlements.plist looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.microphone</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

- I've tried resetting microphone permissions and PRAM to no avail.

Testing without the `--options=runtime` flag works perfectly - the mic prompt appears, and the log file is created. With the flag, neither the prompt nor the log file appears.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or can offer insight into why the hardened runtime option might be causing this? Any guidance or workaround to have the microphone permission prompt appear with hardened runtime enabled would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`com.apple.security.device.microphone` is a sandbox entitlement. For the hardened runtime entitlement, use `com.apple.security.device.audio-input`.
[1](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_device_audio-input)

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion! After updating my `entitlements.plist` to use `com.apple.security.device.audio-input` instead of `com.apple.security.device.microphone`, my application can now correctly prompt for microphone access. Your guidance was incredibly helpful, and I appreciate it greatly!